# How to use "USING" in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wondering if it's possible to use LEFT JOIN table **USING** (id) ... anyone who tried using **"USING"** in laravel query builder?

Normally, a MySQL query statement "**SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)**" can be written in Laravel Query Builder like below...

```
DB::table('t1')->leftJoin('t2','t1.id','=','t2.id')->get();
```

But, how do you write this "**SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING (id)**" in Laravel Query Builder?????

Comment: Using with what ??

Comment: LARAVEL's QUERY BUILDER using "USING" when LEFT JOINING a table...

Comment: haha.. regardless of my level of expertise in Laravel... answering my question will be very helpful...

Comment: `DB::select(DB::raw("YOUR QUERY));`